# Speed: calling by pointer or to access by a vector?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers

I'd like to know which solution could be faster. Let's say we have mB vector of 100 (or n) pointers to objects of B that every each contains a foo() returning a double value:

*Code 1:*

```
int main () {
    vector<double> mA;
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        mA.push_back(mB->at(i)->foo());
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        double a = pow((mA.at(i))*(mA.at(i+1)),2);

    return 0;
}
```

*Code 2:*

```
int main () {
     for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
         double a = pow((mB->at(i)->foo()))*(mB->at(i+1)->foo())),2);

     return 0;
}
```

Code 1 first store the double in a vector, so we have 100 calling to the functions by pointers and then 100+100 accessing to the vector mA. In the second, we have 100+100 calling to the functions by pointes.

1)Is the calling by pointer slower than an access .at() to a vector?
2) which soulution is it better for obtaining a faster code?
Thank you

Comment: No, my code is little different, this i wrote in a rush. is it wrong or you told me that to verify by myself  which is faster?

Comment: Well, since your example code won't even compile, I'm pretty sure it wasn't matching up with your actual code.  But yes, I'm asking if you tried to do any profiling.

Comment: I read this quite a few times but I still don't really understand what you're trying to do. In any case, if all you're looking for is "what's faster?" then there is little reason for this to be on SO. Benchmark it.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I've never done a profiling. I have Visual Studio 2008. Do i have to download a software? (now i am checking the code to understand my mistakes)

Comment: You shouldn't need to download anything.  Use a stopwatch.

Comment: @CarlNorum: ok, I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at the code, the fact that the first snippet has 2 for loops that go to 100 and the second one has only 1 for loop, the first one would probably be slower.
The reason? If checks are super slow, and a for loop has a bunch of them. So, the first code snippet has double the amount of if checks. So, I don't think the difference between both ways of accessing that you're mentioning will play an important factor.

What you could try doing is look at the assembly generated by both, or you could use one of the many ways of timing functions. Since you have visual studio, you can try QueryPerformanceCounter:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815668

Try it and tell us the result!

PS. I suggested changing the title of your question, since you said "Velocity", which would be incorrect, since you're comparing speeds. Probably a better way of asking the question would be "which is faster, accessing... etc etc", but I didn't want to change it too much.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, i will post my example as a new answer

Comment: You're welcome. Also, since I can't comment on other posts, I will put a comment here related to what some other users have said.
Yes, you need to run in release and with large numbers so that there's an actual difference.
Also, rand()%something would "slow" it down since it's a modulus operator. Fast operations are adding and multiplying, even faster ones are bit shifting. Divisions are slower compared to those.
There are looots of profilers that tell you exactly which functions are your "bottlenecks", so you can see what you need to optimize, VTune is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your suggestions, I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include <Windows.h>
 using namespace std;

void StartTimer( _int64 *pt1 )
{
   QueryPerformanceCounter( (LARGE_INTEGER*)pt1 );
}

double StopTimer( _int64 t1 )
{
   _int64 t2, ldFreq;
   QueryPerformanceCounter( (LARGE_INTEGER*)&t2 );
   QueryPerformanceFrequency( (LARGE_INTEGER*)&ldFreq );
   return ((double)( t2 - t1 ) / (double)ldFreq) * 1000.0;
}

int main(){
_int64 t1;
StartTimer( &t1 );

 vector<B*> *mB = new vector<B*>;
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
 mB->push_back(new B());
 A mA(mB);

 printf( "Time = %.3f\n", StopTimer( t1 ));

 system("Pause");
 return 0;
 }
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"

A::A(vector<B*> *mB)
{
 //code1:
 vector<double> mA;
 for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
  mA.push_back(mB->at(i)->foo());
  for (int i=0; i<99; i++)
  cout <<pow((mA.at(i))*(mA.at(i+1)),2)<<endl;
  //code 2:
  //for (int i=0; i<99; i++)
 //cout <<pow((mB->at(i)->foo())*(mB->at(i+1)->foo()),2)<<endl;

}

A::~A(void){}
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

B::B(void):value(10){} //firstly i used rand() maybe affects speed test
B::~B(void){}
double B::foo(){
return value;
 }
```

The results in term of speed is not clear because the time varies in every launch of the debug with both codes it bounces between  20 - 50 milliseconds

EDIT: 
100000 objs:
CODE 1: ~958 milliseconds
CODE 2: ~760 milliseconds

Comment: Suggestions for profiling: Use a larger test, with 10,000 or 100,000 elements instead of 100 so that the running time of the loops is significant in comparison to the startup overhead.  Or, if your actually application only involves 100 elements, just write the code so it is easy to understand and don't worry about optimizing.  Finally, profile in Release mode, not Debug mode.  Many stl functions like .at( ) are likely to add more range-checking overhead in debug that wouldn't happen in release mode.

Comment: @MarkTaylor: thank a lot, i will try it. A question: my true code is huge, is there a way to profile the whole code and understand in which point i should need to improve the speed? or is it only possible to analyze piece by piece? thanks

Comment: MarkTaylor: `.at( )` actually has the overhead in release builds too.  That's what it's for.  If you don't want that overhead, use `[]`.   @Ale: Visual Studio 2008 "development" and "team" editions have profilers to make you drool, otherwise you'll need another program.

Comment: @Ale: note that when profiling, cin/cout and fileIO are _very_ slow.  instead, store the results in an array, and _then_ print them after the timing finishes.  Otherwise the timings will be off, or the compiler may remove the loop altogeather.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet should be faster than both versions of yours, because `at()` does bound checking, whereas `operator[]` does not. The latter may lead to an access out of the vector's boundaries, hence the conditional.

```
if (mB->size() >= 101)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        double a = (*mB)[i]->foo() * (*mB)[i]->foo();
```